# How can I catch which page is load when the back button click on apache cordova?

Tags: cordova, back-button

How can I catch which page is load when the back button click on apache cordova?
I want to know after click the back button which page is load. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
       //console your current page location
       console.log("Page location is " + window.location.href);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```